# Random black screen and pointer moves all over

Tags: display, touchscreen

I have installed Juno on my Asus Laptop 
Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
12.2 GB memory
Randomly I get black screen and the pointer moves all over the place, when it happens it does it continuously for a few seconds, then stops for a while and happens again, sometimes it goes away for while.
Any ideas what this could be???

Comment: When my system behaved like that, it was a video driver issue. (Although my video card isn't one of Intel's.) After I have installed the fresh driver, everything went back to normal.

Comment: I'm new to linux, how can I update my drivers

Comment: I don't know much about Intel drivers installation (sorry!). In case if nobody will offer any insight on the subject, try asking on Ubuntu's StackExchange (https://askubuntu.com), as this issue might be Ubuntu-specific (and elementary OS is Ubuntu-based), or report this issue to elementary OS devs: https://github.com/elementary